# Name like query not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Suppose a user enters 02522 as pin code,all the matching results should be displayed as well as other pin code like 02521,02520 and etc..should also be displayed.
I am able to display exact results for the input but not able to display other matching or nearby results .
Environment : Java Struts2.
Below is my code:

```
package org.entity;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class SearchBasedonBBAction extends ActionSupport {
    BloodBank search2;
    SearchBasedonBB search;
    List<UpdateStock> BBList;
    List<UpdateStock> BBList2;

    public SearchBasedonBBAction() {

    }

    public SearchBasedonBB getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(SearchBasedonBB search) {
        this.search = search;
    }

    public List<UpdateStock> getBBList() {
        return BBList;
    }

    public void setBBList(List<UpdateStock> bBList) {
        BBList = bBList;
    }

    public BloodBank getSearch2() {
        return search2;
    }

    public void setSearch2(BloodBank search2) {
        this.search2 = search2;
    }

    public List<UpdateStock> getBBList2() {
        return BBList2;
    }

    public void setBBList2(List<UpdateStock> bBList2) {
        BBList2 = bBList2;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foryou", "root", "siddheshkk");
            System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement ps = con
                    .prepareStatement("select * from stockinfo where stdcode=?");
            ps.setString(1, search.getBbb());
            BBList = new ArrayList<UpdateStock>();
            BBList2 = new ArrayList<UpdateStock>();
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                BBList.add(new UpdateStock(rs.getString("name"), rs
                        .getString("city"), rs.getString("address"), rs
                        .getString("contact"), rs.getString("email"), rs
                        .getString("apositive"), rs.getString("anegative"), rs
                        .getString("bpositive"), rs.getString("bnegative"), rs
                        .getString("abpositive"), rs.getString("abnegative"),
                        rs.getString("opositive"), rs.getString("onegative")));
            }
            System.out.println("step2");
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con
                    .prepareStatement("select * from stockinfo where stdcode like "
                            + search.getBbb() + "");
            System.out.println("step3");
            ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
            while (rs1.next()) {
                BBList2.add(new UpdateStock(rs.getString("name"), rs
                        .getString("city"), rs.getString("address"), rs
                        .getString("contact"), rs.getString("email"), rs
                        .getString("apositive"), rs.getString("anegative"), rs
                        .getString("bpositive"), rs.getString("bnegative"), rs
                        .getString("abpositive"), rs.getString("abnegative"),
                        rs.getString("opositive"), rs.getString("onegative")));
            }
            System.out.println("Ye b hogya na baa...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.validate();
        if (search.getBbb().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("search.bbb", "Please enter Pin Code");
        }
    }

}
```

See my testing sentences which is written in S.O.P.
Program gets executed but the name like query doesnt gives any output and there is no error .
I get output for 02522 when i enter it in search box but other results of pincode like 02520,02521 are not displayed.

there are two sections one which gives results for the exact one and other which gives for any matching . like in first section if user enters 02522 results exactly matching is displayed and in other section results for 02521,02523 should be displayed.
**Note: stdcode means pincode here (defined as stdcode in DB) **

Answer (score 1):

When you say "nearby results," I'm not sure what you mean. You said that an input of 02522 should match 02521 and 02520. `LIKE` in SQL won't do this. `LIKE` would be used like this:

```
WHERE username LIKE '%hut%'
```

which would match my username, or any username with "hut" in it.

This whole section needs to be fixed as a result:

```
        PreparedStatement ps1 = con
                .prepareStatement("select * from stockinfo where stdcode like "
                        + search.getBbb() + "");
```

because `LIKE` doesn't mean "approximately matches"; it has a more specific meaning that has to do with string matching.

If you want it to match just within a certain range, then you should convert it to an integer and use `BETWEEN`. You don't define what "near" means, so we can't help you until you're a bit more specific.

Comment: I have made some changes in code please read it again sir . sorry for the trouble :(

Comment: @Compiler well now you've changed it so that a null reference shouldn't happen at that point. So please let me know what the new error is; but the rest is still relevant.

Comment: there are two sections one which gives results for the exact one and other which gives for any matching . like in first section if user enters 02522 results exactly matching is displayed and in other section results for 02521,02523 should be displayed and " %" cant be written  when i write %search.getBbb()% . it gives error . so what should be done ?

Comment: @Compiler : You have to define what is meant by "nearby" -- should all results within 5 be displayed? Because that won't help with typos.

Comment: I have mentioned what i need actually in comments sir

Comment: @Compiler Are the stdcodes strings (VARCHAR)? If so, cast them to an INT, then use BETWEEN. You only need one query. If they're always numeric, they should be INTs.

Comment: @Compiler it seems like you're a beginner with this sort of thing, so I should point you to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection which your code is vulnerable to now.

Comment: what should be the query for between if i want to display nearby 5 results ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store the exact pin code value then use between operator with that value like this
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE pin BETWEEN variable AND variable + 5`

Comment: ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery("select * from stockinfo where stdcode between"+search.getBbb()+" and "+search.getBbb()+5+""); this is my query and it says mysql syntax error

Comment: ("select * from stockinfo where stdcode between"+search.getBbb()+" and "+search.getBbb()+5") can you try this and if getBbb returns integer you should convert them to String

Comment: ("select * from stockinfo where stdcode between"+search.getBbb()+" and "+search.getBbb()+"+5") can you try this one and can you write in which part of string it gives error

Comment: Can you tell me at which part of query it gives syntax error

Comment: It runs upto step2 (S.O.P statement) afterwards there is an error

Comment: Can you write the exception with the part where it says the wrong part of sql query  and what type searchBbb() returns?

Comment: it returns string . and i cant attach error image because i dont have more than 10 reputation

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'between02522 and 02522+5' at line 1
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
 this is what i get

Comment: Put space after between. do first part of string like this "select  *  from stockinfo where stdcode between "

Comment: Now it says this ..................
java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:841)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5650)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5570)

Comment: Is it complete stack trace it doesnt say which line in your code does raise exception

Comment: i cant attach complete in comments due to characters limit

Comment: at org.entity.SearchBasedonBBAction.execute(SearchBasedonBBAction.java:73)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:870)
 at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
 at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)

Comment: remaining part of stack trace

Comment: What is in the 73th line of your searchbasedbbaction.java i cant see line numbers im on my phone

Comment: while (rs1.next()) {
    BBList2.add(new UpdateStock(rs.getString("name"), rs
      .getString("city"), rs.getString("address"), rs
      .getString("contact"), rs.getString("email"), rs
      .getString("apositive"), rs.getString("anegative"), rs
      .getString("bpositive"), rs.getString("bnegative"), rs
      .getString("abpositive"), rs.getString("abnegative"),
      rs.getString("opositive"), rs.getString("onegative")));
   }
   line starting from bblist2 is 73rd line

Comment: It might be about rs1.next() debug it and see if it is null or contains no nothing im really sorry i cant help enough im on the phone atm but i will look when i get to pc

Comment: Alright man i checked documentation of [SqlException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html) it says it has values for errorCode and description try to write them to console using System.out.println(e.getMessage()) and System.out.println(Integer.toString(e.getErrorCode())) and tell me what is the output

Comment: Okay i will try and let u know in some hours :)